# Compare two lists and update missing data through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, copy, compare

I have been struggling with the below Excel VBA task.
Within the same workbook there are two worksheets `"Main"` and `"Data"`.
The information in `"Data"` comes from and external source and `"Main"` contains individual comment data that needs to stay on same row as the corresponding ID.

The task here is to run a macro (VBA) that compares the IDs in `"Main"` to the ones within the same first column in `"Data"`. If any IDs are missing it shall copy them from `"Data"` to the first empty row in `"Main"` and sort by `"Main"` ensuring the comments in next cell don't deviate from the corresponding ID.
Attached are screenshot examples:

[image: Main Tab]
[image: Data Tab (compare and copy missing IDs from it)]

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day colleagues,
Thank you for your time and suggestions. I managed to troubleshoot the VBA and will post it here for the benefit of anyone that needs to complete a similar task.
Best regards to all and stay positive.`Sub Compare()

```
'Set Ranges
With Worksheets("Data")
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
compar = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1))
End With
Worksheets("Main").Select
lastdata = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
datar = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastdata, 1))
indi = lastdata + 1

'Logical Test
 For j = 1 To lastrow
  For i = 1 To lastdata
   fnd = False
   If datar(i, 1) = compar(j, 1) Then
    ' When Found
     fnd = True
     Exit For
   End If
  Next i
  If Not (fnd) Then
      For kk = 1 To 1
       Cells(indi, kk) = compar(j, kk)
      Next kk
      indi = indi + 1
  End If
 Next j

'Sort Result
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[ID]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub  `
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide not an answer

Try using code like this;

```
MyListofNewValues = ""
for each TestRow in Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows
   .... get a value to test
   for each CheckRow in Sheets("Main").UsedRange.Rows
      .... Check a value here with the value above
      .... IF Different (ie New) add it to MyListOfNewValues
   next CheckRow
Next TestRow

' Now you have a list of values in Data but Not in Main
' You'll have to add those to main & sort
```

Comeback when you've tried something showing the code you've tried - or post the code you've already tried