# VBA compare filtered list with another list in different workbook and update missing values

Tags: excel, vba

This question is built on a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988121/compare-two-lists-and-update-missing-data-through-excel-vba/71598631#71598631).

I have changed some parts of the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988121/compare-two-lists-and-update-missing-data-through-excel-vba/71598631#71598631) code to suit my purpose. The code is supposed to compare two lists:

- The first list should be filtered based on certain criterion before the comparison *(in this sample code it should display any value above 3333 in the ID column in the Data sheet **attached**)*
- The comparison is meant to check if there is a missing value in the second list that does exist in the first list then add it
- Finally the second list should be sorted from smallest to largest

After running the code, I discovered that the filtered value 1122 which is not meeting the criteria is the only value copied to the main sheet **attached** and I'm not sure where exactly I did wrong..

The code:

```
    Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">3333", Operator:=xlAnd
'Set Ranges
With Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Data")
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
filteredrow = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
compar = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(filteredrow, 1))
End With
Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Main").Activate
lastdata = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
datar = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastdata, 1))
indi = lastdata + 1

'Logical Test
 For j = 1 To filteredrow
  For i = 1 To lastdata
   fnd = False
   If datar(i, 1) = compar(j, 1) Then
    ' When Found
     fnd = True
     Exit For
   End If
  Next i
  If Not (fnd) Then
      For kk = 1 To 1
       Cells(indi, kk) = compar(j, kk)
      Next kk
      indi = indi + 1
  End If
 Next j

'Sort Result
Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[ID]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Main").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

The current result:

[Main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbxEV.png)

[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KelcH.png)

Comment: Could you share what the code is supposed to do? I mean, you are filtering a table and then you are fiddling around in its worksheet. Then you are fiddling around in another worksheet and sorting a table in it. The screenshots aren't of any use either. Please do clarify what needs to be filtered, copied, compared, etc. and where to. Surely you can do better. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71634871/edit) at any time.

Comment: Hi  @VBasic2008 I have added more details to the question. Sorry for not being clear enough.